# Error in Android client that sends byte[] to a REST web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, httpclient

this is my first post; i'm a newbie on Android development, i wrote a REST web service for receiving a byte[]:

```
@Path("scp")
public class ScpResources {

    // ...  

    @POST
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)    
    public String upload(byte[] input) {

        System.out.println("Input: " + new String(input));

        return "File Sent!";
    }    

} // End
```

I tested this ws with a java stand alone application(apache httpclient libraries), and everything is ok, but, when i try to do the same thing in the Android application... :

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";   

    @Override /** Called when the activity is first created. */    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.v(TAG, "--------------> to WS");

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            String tmp = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            byte b[] = tmp.getBytes();            
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.116:8080/WSfEclipse/resources/scp");  

            ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(b);
            entity.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            Log.e(TAG, ">Before error");
            //if(client == null) Log.e(TAG, "HttpClient null");
            //if(httpPost == null) Log.e(TAG, "HttpPost null");            

            client.execute(httpPost); // ERROR            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //if(e == null) Log.e(TAG, "Exception(e) null");
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

    } // End : onCreate

} // End : MainActivity
```

... the logcat prints:

```
ERROR/MainActivity(368):   >Before error
    AndroidRuntime(368):   Shutting down VM
WARNING/dalvikvm(368):     threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.....
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:230)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(368):     ... 11 more
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.edu.radiogis.scpecg.clientecelular.activities"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="ClienteSCP">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="ClienteSCP">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

When i removed the catch code, no errors appear; nevertheless, the application doesn't send the bytes to the web service. I checked if there were null references(Using the code in the comments), but everything was ok. I don't know what is happening, maybe i'm forgetting something.

!!Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Side note, you should never do potentially long running operations on the UI thread. It will block everything and you'll get the infamous Application Not Responding dialog. Checkout this to see how to do things the right way: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 2):

What you see is an exception raised by Log.e method, because the message text you pass to it (e.getMessage) is null.

You should check what kind of exception you get from your http code. Replace your logging statement with e.printStackTrace().

Answer (score 2):

i found the solution, the package was ok(sorry i didn't show the package statement), i used e.printStackTrace(), and it shows Android NetworkOnMainThreadException, so i moved the code to an AsyncTask:

```
public class WSConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

HttpClient client;
HttpPost httpPost; 
HttpResponse response;

String tmp = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
byte[] b;   

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    b = tmp.getBytes();  
} // End : onPreExecute 

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.116:8080/WSfEclipse/resources/scp");      
    ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(b);
    entity.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    try {
        client.execute(httpPost); // Send request       
    }
    catch (Exception e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return "OK";

} // End : doInBackground

} // End : WSConnectionTask
```

And !!Jackpot!!, success, thank you so much.

Comment: accept your answer if no other answers led you to this solution.  There are a lot of open questions in the Android tag (30,000 of them) so please help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception and the lack of a package definition in your code, I am thinking that you have forgotten to place your code in the package that is listed in the Manifest, specifically this:  `com.edu.radiogis.scpecg.clientecelular.activities`

Comment: MainActivity.onCreate is executed:

...
at MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
...